# Dealing with invalid characters from web scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I've written a web scraper to extract a large amount of information from a website using Nokigiri and Mechanize, which outputs a database seed file. Unfortunately, I've discovered there's a lot of invalid characters in the text on the source website, things like `keppnisÃ¦find`, `ScÃ©mario` and `KlÃ¤tiring`, which is preventing the seed file from running. The seed file is too large to go through with search and replace, so how can I go about dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think those are html characters, all you need do is to write functions that will clean the characters. This depends on the programming platform

Comment: I don't think they are HTML characters, as I tried to use HTMLEntities to convert: http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/, but it did not convert them.

Answer (score 0):

Those are almost certainly UTF-8 characters; the words should look like keppnisæfind, Scémario and Klätiring. The web sites in question might be sending UTF-8 but not declaring that as their encoding, in which case you will have to force Mechanize to use UTF-8 for sites with no declared encoding. However, that might complicate matters if you encounter other web sites without a declared encoding and they send something besides UTF-8.

Comment: All the data is coming from the same web site. I tried setting the encoding using `agent.get("http://website.com")
    agent.page.encoding = 'utf-8'` but am not seeing any change.